# Traffic control - bandwidth and jitter colidation for Quic

Tags: tc, traffic-shaping

I am currently experimenting with the Quic and TCP protocols, aiming to simulate real network conditions using TC. However, I encountered an issue when attempting to set the bandwidth to 32mbit, with a loss of 0.1%, a delay of 20ms, and jitter of 1ms. While TCP performs as expected, Quic's speed is significantly slower, approximately 250KB/s compared to TCP's 3.6MB/s.

Upon further exploration, I discovered that removing jitter and setting it to 0ms allowed Quic to perform normally, exhibiting similar performance to TCP. Additionally, resetting jitter to 1ms while removing the rate limit also resulted in normal behavior. However, when both jitter and rate limit were set together, Quic exhibited unusual behavior.

I also tried to modify delay and loss but it was acting normally as I would expect.

I am using [quic-go](https://github.com/quic-go/quic-go) implementation of Quic. Example code of TC configuration is below:

```
tc qdisc add dev "$interface" root handle 1: htb default 10
tc class add dev "$interface" parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate 32mbit ceil 32mbit
tc class add dev "$interface" parent 1:1 classid 1:10 htb rate 32mbit ceil 32mbit
tc class add dev "$interface" parent 1:1 classid 1:20 htb rate 32mbit ceil 32mbit
tc filter add dev "$interface" parent 1: protocol ip prio 16 u32 match ip protocol 17 0xff flowid 1:10
tc filter add dev "$interface" parent 1: protocol ip prio 16 u32 match ip protocol 6 0xff flowid 1:20
        
tc qdisc add dev "$interface" parent 1:10 handle 100: netem delay 20ms 1ms loss 0.2%
tc qdisc add dev "$interface" parent 1:20 handle 200: netem delay 20ms 1ms loss 0.2%
```

I am uncertain if this behavior is related to a bug in the jitter and packet ordering within the Quic implementation, as the issue seems to be resolved when bandwidth limitations are removed. Any insights or ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.